# Error 403 Forbidden: Docker and ASP.NET 4.7

Tags: asp.net, docker

I am trying to create a docker container for my ASP.NET 4.7 application and no matter what I seem to do, when I try to access my container with localhost:8000 I am getting this error, I've been banging my head off the wall for 3 hours now and I decided to finally cave and ask for help since I can't get this working. PLEASE HELP.

My DockerFile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
EXPOSE 80
COPY . /inetpub/wwwroot
```

Commands I am executing from the root of my web app alongside the Dockerfile

```
docker build -t mytestapp .
docker run -d --name mytestapp --rm -p 8000:80 mytestapp:latest
```

[image]

Comment: In general you need things like FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis . To configure such for your container, learn how to set those rules via PowerShell and then use the commands in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Did you make sure you have routing enabled correctly? This error likely has nothing to do with Docker. Did you run the app outside of Docker?

Comment: App works 100% outside docker (as in IISExpress or when I deploy to Azure

Comment: Did you compile your app before copying it into the container?

Comment: Yes. So basically I’m in the bin output directory with all the compiled assemblies. The Dockerfile is in the same directory. This is the webroot basically.

Comment: You need to copy the root of your web app to the folder where IIS in the container is looking. You haven’t described exactly what folder you’re copying from. Are you directly where the DLLs for your app are? The global.asax etc?

Comment: Yes I am in the same directly as all of the DLLS I even tried adding a single index.html file to no avail. I believe IIS is looking in /inetpub/wwwroot and that’s where I’m trying to copy to if you look at my Dockerfile.

Comment: `I believe IIS is looking in /inetpub/wwwroot` => Did you check that ? What do the webserver logs (access/error) tell you inside the docker container ?